# Does all the C compiler strictly follows operator precedence order

Tags: c, compiler-construction, programming-languages, operators

I am writing c program, which will be compiled in most of the C compilers in world (compilers of windows, linux, solaris, mac, aix, hpux, vxworks(arm, ppc, mips...), windriver linux and etc.)

Will it be fine if I write the program based on the C standard [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)

Comment: Well, nobody know which are _all_ C compilers.. All _standard_ and self-respecting compilers **must** follow the operator precedence order, it's defined by the _standard_.

Comment: Raja is probably coming from the web world where implementations of "standards" (I know they don't use the term) like HTML were first hopelessly fragmented and only later, slowly made a bit more compliant. C compilers are much, much more standards compliant than that.

Comment: All conforming compilers will obey the same precedence rules; you will be fine.

Comment: All compilers will follow the precedence rules; however, don't fall into the trap of believing that precedence enforces an evaluation order. For example, in the expression `(a() + b()) * (c() - d()) ` the compiler is free to call the functions in the following order (in addition to many others):  `d()`, `b()`, `a()`, `c()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be fine.

But, when in doubt, use parenthesis!

```
int a = 2 * 3 / 4;   /* 0 or 1 ? */
int b = (2 * 3) / 4; /* definitely 1 */
int c = 2 * (3 / 4); /* definitely 0 */
```

It's much much better to have redundant parenthesis than a wrong result.

Comment: To clarify, the first is not really "0 or 1". The comment "0 or 1 ?" means "The naive reader is not sure at first whether it's 0 or 1," though I might be more worried about a naive reader thinking it's 1.5... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In general, languages almost never leave parsing unspecified, because parsing according to a specification is fairly easy for language designers, and parsing doesn't affect the performance of the resulting program.